# Keycloak - read-only user attributes

Tags: keycloak

I want to keep some information in Keycloak as custom user attributes.

Some of them should be managed by the user itself. Other attributes should be managed only by a Keycloak administrator. Attributes managed by the administrator should be read-only visible in the "Edit account" web page for the user.

I went through the [guide to add custom user attributes in this page](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes) and customized the "Edit account" web page.

**My question is:**
Is it ensured that the user cannot change the attribute that is meant as read-only for the user? E.g. by submitting a form where he/she sends correct data that will be automatically mapped on the server side to the user attribute.

Comment: Do you want some of your custom attributes to be read only? Or do you mean the attributes keycloak has already set for the user?

Comment: I want some of my custom attributes to be read only.

Comment: Then how are they meant to be set by the user? Or do you set them from other part of your application?

Comment: I set them from another part of the application.

Comment: I tried to POST the FORM from Postman including a user attribute that is not defined in the UI template and it succeeded. It means a logged-in user may create or update any user attribute it wants. Even they are not defined in the UI template. Isn't it a security bug?

Comment: It seems that custom user attributes are not constrained in the backend in any way. I guess this is a by-dessign choice. Your application will only use what it's  considered in it.

Comment: Yes, my application will use just what it is considered in it. I'm thinking to implement `org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction` to validate what it is possible to change and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perform an update to version 12.0.4.
There were some issues < 12.0.4 with dropping all attributes if user updates his profile.

Additionally with 12.0.4 you can create user- and admin-read only attributes.

Check documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_read_only_user_attributes

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For what you've said, it seems that you have three choices.

**One** would be to keep the keycloak "Edit Account" page and use an [update profile listener](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/requiredactions/UpdateProfile.java) to check what attributes are stored or which ones are updated by who, something like this:

```java
public class UpdateProfile implements RequiredActionProvider, RequiredActionFactory, DisplayTypeRequiredActionFactory {
    @Override
    public InitiatedActionSupport initiatedActionSupport() {
        return InitiatedActionSupport.SUPPORTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluateTriggers(RequiredActionContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void requiredActionChallenge(RequiredActionContext context) {
        Response challenge = context.form()
                .createResponse(UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PROFILE);
        context.challenge(challenge);
    }

    // Check the custom attribute 1 not being modified by the user
    @Override
    public void processAction(RequiredActionContext context) {
        EventBuilder event = context.getEvent();
        event.event(EventType.UPDATE_PROFILE);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
        UserModel user = context.getUser();
        KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();
        RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();

        String newYourCustomAttribute1 = formData.getFirst("yourCustomAttribute1");
        String oldYourCustomAttribute1 = user.getFirstAttribute("yourCustomAttribute1") 

        if (!newYourCustomAttribute1.equals(oldYourCustomAttribute1)) {
            Response challenge = context.form()
                    .setError("User cannot change the attribute")
                    .setFormData(formData)
                    .createResponse(UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PROFILE);
            context.challenge(challenge);
            return;
        }
        context.success();

    }


    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public RequiredActionProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public RequiredActionProvider createDisplay(KeycloakSession session, String displayType) {
        if (displayType == null) return this;
        if (!OAuth2Constants.DISPLAY_CONSOLE.equalsIgnoreCase(displayType)) return null;
        return ConsoleUpdateProfile.SINGLETON;
    }



    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayText() {
        return "Update Profile";
    }


    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PROFILE.name();
    }
}
```

What I don't know is if this listener will be called when you update the profile from your client application too. If it gets called, you'll need to check which is the logged in client, if it's the public client do not let update the attributes, if it's your service client, let it.

**The second one** would be to only let your service client update the user profiles and make a custom view in your application which sends a form POST to your client, instead of to keycloak directly. This way you can validate it in the service before sending it to keycloak.

**The third one** is [to implement](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#modifying-extending-the-registration-form) a `FormAction` interface, which would allow you to validate the incoming form at server side:

> The core interface you have to implement is the FormAction interface. A FormAction is responsible for rendering and processing a portion of the page. Rendering is done in the buildPage() method, validation is done in the validate() method, post validation operations are done in success().

```java
@Override
public void validate(ValidationContext context) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
    UserModel user = context.getUser();
    KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();
    RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();

    String newYourCustomAttribute1 = formData.getFirst("yourCustomAttribute1");
    String oldYourCustomAttribute1 = user.getFirstAttribute("yourCustomAttribute1") 

    if (!newYourCustomAttribute1.equals(oldYourCustomAttribute1)) {
        Response challenge = context.form()
                .setError("User cannot change the attribute")
                .setFormData(formData)
                .createResponse(UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PROFILE);
        context.challenge(challenge);
        return;
    }
    context.success();
}
```

Comment: The first option does not work for me. It validates user attributes only after the registration. User may change them later on by using the "Edit account" page.

Comment: @Apolo-11 check out the third choice in my answer, I guess this is what you told in your last comment

Comment: The third choice (FormAction) does also not work. These actions do not apply for Edit user page. You can use them only in authentication flows.

Comment: @Apolo-11 IMO, the first option not working its a big dessign flaw in keycloak. The listener should definitelly be called, even if you as admin don't specifically request the end user action. I've been digging a bit and [this user](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-January/016994.html) happens to have the same issue. You still can go with the second option, but I would mail the team in the lists about this, if I were you.